# Error where creating a SessionSlack with bot user auth token: Item may not be null

Tags: android, slack-api, slack

i want to connect my android app with slack by using this [library](https://github.com/Ullink/simple-slack-api)!

i got an exception message :"Item may not be null" when executing this code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {

                String bot_auth="this is just an example ";
                SlackSession session = SlackSessionFactory.createWebSocketSlackSession(bot_auth);
                session.connect();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"error :"+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```